# NodeJS - Store Global variable

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm currently trying to get a list of all of the members that are signed in. I'm using socket.js for this and using event handlers.

I have the following event:

```
eventEmitter.on('userSignedIn', function(socket, user) { 
   socket.emit("userJoined", {currentUsers: user.first_name});
});
```

Then, in JQuery, I am doing the following:

```
socket.on('userJoined', function (message) {
              newItem = $("<li>Item " + message.currentUsers + "</li>").show();
              $('.users-list').prepend(newItem);
          });
```

This however is not working and not even showing the correct username(s).

Basically, what I want to do is when the event `userSignedIn` it appends an array `users` with the user that's just signed and then send this through the socket. But I'm struggling to see how I can store this inside the global app?

Comment: Which global scope are you talking about? The one in your server or the one in the browser?

Comment: @slebetman It would be on the server as it would need to record the number of users that are currently signed in. Basically, an object that increments each time a user signs in.

Answer (score 0):

A global variable in node is accessed through [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html).

If you need to store this as a global variable in Node, go to the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module, install it, (farily simple to use it) and use it to store your original global for the counter. In your .env file you would have say `counter=1`. Then you can increment it by accessing the global in your code by stating process.env.counter and  you can increment it as well.

Remember: if you process stops running or goes down the counter will return to the original state of 1 when you bring it back up.

You can if you wish not use the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module and simply create and access a process.env variable straight in your code. However, [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is very flexible, and you may want to use it for other purposes.

Hope this helps

Comment: @twig - thanks for this but is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @Phorce There is another way which would be to create a simple cache on your server, say with [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache), and then placing your counter in there. It is fairly simple to use and efficient to hold this sort of information. (It is a cache after all :)